# Android Studio 3.1 gradle hangs when downloading maven2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

On the build screen everything works fine except the downloads of two dependencies:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.0/sdk-common-26.1.0.jar

And

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.0/builder-3.1.0.jar

Maven is trying to resolve each download for 20 mins, and after 20 minutes it finishe with a:

> org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.0/sdk-common-26.1.0.jar'

Caused by:

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.barakiva.sqlite"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```